# Update nested property by condition in MongoEngine

Tags: python, database, mongodb, mongoengine, mongodb-update

I have MonogoDB collection described with following MongoEngine document:

```
class Inner(EmbeddedDocument):
    value = StringField()

class Outer(Document):
    inner = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Inner)
```

So `db.outer` collection in MongoDB can look like this:

```
{ "inner": [{ "value": "A" }, { "value": "B" }] },
{ "inner": [{ "value": "B" }] },
{ "inner": [] }
```

Now, I would like to update all `inner.value`, where old value is "B" to "C", so desired result is:

```
{ "inner": [{ "value": "A" }, { "value": "C" }] },
{ "inner": [{ "value": "C" }] },
{ "inner": [] }
```

In native MongoDB, I can use this query:

```
db.outer.updateMany(
    {},
    { "$set": { "inner.$[current].value": "C" }},
    { "arrayFilters": [{ "current.value": "B" }]}
)
```

Is there any way to do that in MongoEngine? And if no, can I somehow run native `updateMany` query? I know only about aggregation (`Outer.objects.aggregate`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this not very clean (_get_collection should not be public) solution:

```
Outer._get_collection().update_many(
   {},
   {"$set": {"inner.$[current].value": "C"}},
   array_filters=[{"current.value": "B"}]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to do this is to use `__raw__`, that would allow passing any mongo conditions when working with mongoengine tables - see more here: https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#raw-queries